# How can I use grep to return the full string of text that a searched term is nested in?

Tags: unix, command-line, grep

Lets say I have the following text:

> Hi my name is Larry and this is my profile www.cool.com/imgreat please check it out.

```
egrep -i --color 'cool' filename
```

Just highlights the occurrence of 'cool' in the string but I would like it to return 'www.cool.com/imgreat'

Comment: You'll get the whole like. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple `awk` to loop through the entries one by one and if any of the row entries match `cool` print the whole word.

```
$ string="Hi my name is Larry and this is my profile www.cool.com/imgreat please check it out"
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i ~ /cool/){print $i}}}' <<<"$string"
www.cool.com/imgreat
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, this should be the regex that match the pattern of a website (this does not comprend http/https):
`[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&=]*)`
So your command should be:

```
    egrep -i --color '[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&=]*)' filename
```

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to extract the part containing `cool` delimited by WS, you can use awk

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++) if ($i ~ /cool/)print $i}' <<< """Hi my name is Larry and this is my profile www.cool.com/imgreat please check it out."""
www.cool.com/imgreat
```